# Primitive Integer Operation

Tags: alloy

I am trying to compare 2 sets of element related by a binary relation which as an effect that

```
#set1 = #set0 + 2
```

Apparently in this expression the 2 is interpreted as `{}`, that is what the evaluator tells me, so the expression returns `true`.
The book says that `+` arithmetic operator is detected automatically. But apparently the problem is more about how to express the 2 in arithmetic. In the book I saw an example which is exactly what I want to do.

Moreover, when I calculate `#Set`, which contains `set1+set0` the evaluator returns me a negative value.

Does someone have an idea about this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sig A {}
sig B {}

pred show{ #A = add[#B, 2]}

run show for 5
```

As far as I understand there is special function for adding integers.
Let me know if I understood you right.